# Combinatorics and count

Tags: combinatorics

The sum of the digits of a positive integer less than 1000 is 14.

How many such integers exist.

Please provide the complete solution.

Comment: Why should we provide a complete solution? We are not homework solving community. You should also show your efforts, and put that into your question.

Comment: @JaideepKhare this is not home work I am working on some problems of combinatorics and I am facing issues comprehending the solution.

Comment: @MaryLopez Please show what you have attempted so we can see where you have gone wrong.

Comment: @MaryLopez Whatever may be the case, we don't generally answer those questions which don't show any attempt.

Comment: @JaideepKhare I'll put my attempt once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can distinguish ten different values for the first digit. Then, we must divide the remainder over the last two digits. As such, we get:

First digit 9: 6 solutions (5-0, 4-1, 3-2, 2-3, 1-4, 0-5)
First digit 8: 7 solutions
First digit 7: 8 solutions
First digit 6: 9 solutions
First digit 5: 10 solutions
First digit 4: 9 solutions
First digit 3: 8 solutions
First digit 2: 7 solutions
First digit 1: 6 solutions
First digit 0: 5 solutions

In total, there are 75 possible solutions.

Comment: OP said they were going to put an attempt at a solution in... why provide a full answer when they have said this? If you were so eager, a hint would have sufficed.

Comment: @JohnDoe I had already prepared my answer when the OP commented. The downvote is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: I feel like if you had waited until they posted, it would have been better. Anyhow, they have posted an answer which looks good, but I cannot undo my downvote unless you make a (minor?) edit.

Answer (score 3):

3 digit numbers
$a + b + c = 14$
$a' + b + c= 13 \implies {{15}\choose{2}}$
$a'' + b + c = 4 \implies {6\choose2}$
$a' + b' + c = 3 \implies {5\choose2} * 2$
total = ${15\choose2} - {6\choose2} - {5\choose2} *2 = 70$

2 digit numbers,
$a + b = 14$
$a'+ b = 13 \implies {14\choose1}$
$a" + b = 4 \implies {5\choose1}$
$a' + b' = 3 \implies {4\choose1}$
total $= 14 - 5 - 4 = 5$

so, total possibilties $= 70 + 5 = 75$